# How to deploy a Websockets App on GAE flexible?

Tags: google-app-engine, deployment, websocket, jetty, app-engine-flexible

I have a spring boot application that I want to deploy on Google App Engine Flexible. This container/web-server for this App is Jetty 9.4 and since Jetty runs on Websockets internally, [GAE doesn't allow me to deploy the App.](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/flexible/nodejs/how-requests-are-handled#not_supported)

My question is that, is there any workaround for supporting Websockets on GAE or maybe remove the Websockets support(which would mean removing it from Jetty somehow) ?

Comment: I'm having the same issue. Some articles say websockets isn't supported on the flexible environment, while others say it's possible (all authored by Google). It's terribly confusing

Comment: Websockets are not supported by Google App Engine flexible environment. WebSockets were removed in Aug 2017 (here is the commit from their docs -> [18210b3](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/nodejs-docs-samples/commit/18210b3bd741da95b42fbea884922ef4c7cd57fe)). All the docs that are saying it supports must be written before that time. 

Google recommends to use "Compute Engine" if you have to use websockets.